# Elasticsearch `function_score` with `score_mode` confusion when used with nested objects

Tags: elasticsearch, nested

**Background:**

I have the following mapping for `curriculum_posts` documents. Notice the nested `skills` property.

```
{
  "curriculum_posts" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "dynamic" : "false",
      "properties" : {
        "title" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "analyzer" : "english"
        },
        "skills" : {
          "type" : "nested",
          "properties" : {
            "slug" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "raw" : {
                  "type" : "keyword"
                },
                "text" : {
                  "type" : "text"
                }
              }
            },
            "start_skill_level" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            },
            "start_skill_level_value" : {
              "type" : "integer"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

A sample record looks like this:

```
{
  "_source" : {
    "skills" : [
      {
        "start_skill_level_value" : 1,
        "slug" : "infrastructure-as-code-iac"
      },
      {
        "start_skill_level_value" : 1,
        "slug" : "devops"
      }
    ],
    "title" : "Terraform: Infrastructure as code"
  }
}
```

I wanted to run a query that return all documents but with scores matching the number of `skills.slug` values that matched. My query looks like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "skills",
      "query": {
        "function_score": {
          "query": { "match_all": {} },
          "functions": [
            { "script_score": { "script": "0" } },
            { 
              "filter": { 
                "term": { "skills.slug.raw": { "value": "devops" } }
              },  
              "weight": 2
            },
            { 
              "filter": { 
                "term": { "skills.slug.raw": { "value": "infrastructure-as-code-iac" } }
              },  
              "weight": 2
            }
          ],
          "score_mode": "sum",
          "boost_mode": "replace"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I decided to use `function_score` with `boost_mode: replace` so that the scores from documents are ignored and only the function scores are taken. The `score_mode: sum` to ensure that the scores from the function matches are summed up.

**The problem**

So, for the above query, on the example document above, I was **expecting the score** to be `4.0` because it matches the `skills.slug` for both `infrastructure-as-code-iac` and `devops`. However, I the **score in the result** is only `2.0` for the document.

**Question**

I suppose I'm not understanding how `function_score` takes the scores from the functions or how my functions are effecting the score. Could someone help me understand the scoring here?

**Some debugging**

I looked at the explanation but I'm unable to decode much information from it. Nevertheless, here is the explanation:

```
{
  "_index" : "curriculum_posts",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "18",
  "matched" : true,
  "explanation" : {
    "value" : 2.0,
    "description" : "Score based on 2 child docs in range from 83 to 93, best match:",
    "details" : [
      {
        "value" : 2.0,
        "description" : "sum of:",
        "details" : [
          {
            "value" : 2.0,
            "description" : "min of:",
            "details" : [
              {
                "value" : 2.0,
                "description" : "function score, score mode [sum]",
                "details" : [
                  {
                    "value" : 0.0,
                    "description" : "script score function, computed with script:\"Script{type=inline, lang='painless', idOrCode='0', options={}, params={}}\"",
                    "details" : [
                      {
                        "value" : 1.0,
                        "description" : "_score: ",
                        "details" : [
                          {
                            "value" : 1.0,
                            "description" : "*:*",
                            "details" : [ ]
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "value" : 2.0,
                    "description" : "function score, product of:",
                    "details" : [
                      {
                        "value" : 1.0,
                        "description" : "match filter: skills.slug.raw:infrastructure-as-code-iac",
                        "details" : [ ]
                      },
                      {
                        "value" : 2.0,
                        "description" : "product of:",
                        "details" : [
                          {
                            "value" : 1.0,
                            "description" : "constant score 1.0 - no function provided",
                            "details" : [ ]
                          },
                          {
                            "value" : 2.0,
                            "description" : "weight",
                            "details" : [ ]
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "value" : 3.4028235E38,
                "description" : "maxBoost",
                "details" : [ ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "value" : 0.0,
            "description" : "match on required clause, product of:",
            "details" : [
              {
                "value" : 0.0,
                "description" : "# clause",
                "details" : [ ]
              },
              {
                "value" : 1.0,
                "description" : "_type:__skills",
                "details" : [ ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```